# Why isn't the fourth component rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-component

Sorry for the awful indentation but why isn't the fourth about component rendering. I've tried everything even tried to write about component in seperate file but the outcome is same. In the `App.js` third class component is about and I've exported and imported in `index.js` it like `Rcomp1` component which renders fine .

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import { ProgressBar } from 'react-bootstrap';


import './App.css';
//everything css

var ele;
var col;
var f;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ele = this.props.imgUrl;
    col = this.props.colour;
  }

  render() {
    console.log(ele);
    var font = {
      fontFamily: "Times New Roman"
    }

    var divStyle = {
      backgroundColor: col,
      height: 390
    };

    var divs = {
      height: 390,
      backgroundColor: col
    };

    var newde = {
      backgroundImage: `url(${ele})`,
      height: 390
    };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row" style={divs} >
            <div className="col-xs-6 " style={divStyle} >
              <div className='padding' style={newde}></div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-6 Back">
              <p className="font">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

var c;

class Rcomp1 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    f = this.props.fa;
    c = this.props.colour;
  }

  render() {
    var tyle = {
      backgroundColor: this.props.bg,
      height: 360,
      color: c
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <div className='container-fluid'>
          <div className='row' style={{ height: 360 }}>
            <div className='col-xs-8 ' style={tyle}>
              <div className='marg marg3'>
                <p className='font2'><strong>Information about my skills.</strong></p>
                <p className='font2'><strong>{this.props.skill1}</strong></p>
                <ProgressBar className="wid" bsStyle="success" now={this.props.ski1} />
                <p className='font2'><strong>{this.props.skill2}</strong></p>
                <ProgressBar className="wid" bsStyle="success" now={this.props.ski2} />
                <p className='font2'><strong>{this.props.skill3}</strong></p>
                <ProgressBar className="wid" bsStyle="success" now={this.props.ski3} />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='col-xs-4' style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.bg, height: 360 }}>
              <div className='marg2  marg4' style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.bg }}>
                <i className={" fa fa-5x " + " " + f + " fs text-primary"} style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.bg }}></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class about extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='container-fluid'>
        hellow world
            <div className='col-xs-4'>
          Hello
            </div>
        <div className='col-xs-5'>
          World
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
export { Rcomp1 };
export { about };
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { Rcomp1 } from './App';
import { about } from './App';
import './index.css';
import r from './r.jpeg';
import { Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { NavbarHeader } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { DropdownButton } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { NavbarBrand } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { NavBarToggle } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <div><App imgUrl="https://www.hrii.tk/skate.webp" colour="#FA9F1B" />
    <Rcomp1 fa={"fa-linkedin"} colour={'#FFFFFF'} bg={'#263238'} skill1={'GITHUB'} ski1={25} skill2={'HTML5'} ski2={50} skill3={'BOOTSTRAP'} ski3={30} />
    <App imgUrl="https://www.hrii.tk/tri1.webp" colour='#3E384F' />
    <Rcomp1 fa={"fa-github-square"} colour={"#FFFFFF"} bg={'black'} skill1={'C/C++'} ski1={85} skill2={'PYTHON'} ski2={70} skill3={'JQUERY'} ski3={40} />
    <about />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <div style={{ backgroundColor: '#F99F1C' }}>
    <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect className='fon'>
      <Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Brand>
          <a href="#brand" className='fon fon2'>Hrii.tk</a>
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle />
      </Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Collapse>
        <Nav>
          <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
            Link
            </NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">
            Link
            </NavItem>
          <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
            <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem divider />
            <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Separated link</MenuItem>
          </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
        <Nav pullRight>
          <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
            Link Right
            </NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">
            Link Right
            </NavItem>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>;
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('navbar')
);
```

Comment: This is a bad app structure for a React app. Where did you learn to set it up this way? You should only have one `ReactDOM.render` and it should be rendering out your main `<App />` component. So everything you have in the first render should be moved to a separate component called `Main` or `Home` and then it should have `Nav` stuff and all the `<App>` and `<Rcomp>` components.

Comment: sorry i'v just started to learn it thanks for telling me i'm kind of new to this i will follow the structure you told  next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because all components MUST start with a capital letter! So if you change `class about extends Component` to `class About extends Component`, then it will work. You'll also need to update your export and imports to be `<About />`.

Comment: thank you  it worked,  i didn't know that all components must  start with a capital letter